# Chromium is not able to access pipewire-pulse's virtual-sink.monitor

Tags: pulseaudio, chromium, pipewire

When trying to run chromium on a headless ubuntu server, chromium is printing below error

```shell
[48089:48089:0820/175843.665081:ERROR:pulse_util.cc(351)] pa_operation is nullptr.
```

Here is some information

`pactl info`

```shell
Server String: /run/user/1001/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 51
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: xxxxx
Host Name: ip-xx-x-xx-xxx
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.48)
Server Version: 15.0.0
Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: virtual-sink
Default Source: virtual-source
Cookie: xxxx:xxxx
```

`pactl list sources short`

```shell
43      virtual-sink.monitor    PipeWire        float32le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
44      virtual-source  PipeWire        float32le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
```

I am using the below cmdline switch on chrome

```shell
--alsa-output-device=virtual-sink.monitor
```

I am trying to play some sound from chromium and trying to record it using ffmpeg. I tried to search through debug logs of both chromium and pipewire but was not able to find any explanation of the error or why the audio is coming through.